# Even distribution of cells in table

Tags: tabularx

I need to display the n-column table (let's say 5), with values. The table should fill up the available space entirely. 
But I need to have even spacing between columns which will automatically adjust depending on the available space.

How to achieve that nice even spacing? I tried `\hfill`  but it didn't worked.

[![The problem in the picture][1]][1]

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|llllll|}
        \hline
            this&  negligible& countless& sizeable& any\\
        \hline            
            reassembling& impoverished& political& backlash& devastating \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    Table 1
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XXXXXX|}
        \hline
            this&  negligible& countless& sizeable& any\\
        \hline            
            reassembling& impoverished& political& backlash& devastating \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    Table 2
\end{table}

\end{document}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yST9G.png
````

Comment: ![The problem in the picture][1]][1] ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? The commands

```
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}
```

secure that the tabular fills available space between margins. `\noindent` is necessary if you do not place the tabular in a table-environment (or centring it).

```
{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{c}}
```

set five ordinary (one line) centred columns which width will adapt to the cells content. You may use `l`or `r` instead.

The declaration

```
@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
```

together with

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
```

ensure that the space that remains after all the columns is set to their natural width, will be evenly distributed as space between the columns. See the three last lines in the second example to see the effect clearly.

**Centred columns**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{c}}
\hline
unqualified &member & is &unavoidable &sometimes\\\midrule
sad & situation & but & my & boss \\
which & predominate & in & Asia & although \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 

\end{document}
```

**Left aligned columns**

[image]

```
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{l}}
\hline
unqualified & member & is &unavoidable &sometimes\\\midrule
sad & situation & but & my & boss \\
which & dominate & in & Asia & although \\

1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890\\
1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890\\
1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890 & 1234567890\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
```